# ASP.NET issue wih IE10 opening files stored in sql server DB

Tags: asp.net, content-disposition

I have a little asp.net application which allows users to upload attachments, and via an asp:linkbutton download them from another screen.  in IE10, when I click on the linkbutton to download the uploaded file, IR shows the open, save, cancel dialog but it shows the URL in place of the file name.  In safari and firefox this does not happen.  it's driving me nuts.  I've tried all kinda of header/content type, content disposition combinations with no luck.  below is a snippet of my code which works in firefox and safari -- it simply writes the binary to the response.

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("UploadedFiles"), Byte())
Response.Clear()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ClearContent()
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Chr(34) & 
dt.Rows(0)    ("FileName").ToString & Chr(34))
Response.Buffer = True
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
Response.End()
```

Comment: So just to confirm `filename=`part doesn't work? It doesn't display correct file name to "Save as" ?

Comment: correct, it shows the open/save/cancel dialog, but my pagename with querystring parameter is shows instead of the filename.  because of this, IE can't open the file.  firefox and safari work fine.

Comment: I think caching could be an issue. Can you try `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)` instead and also add `Response.AddHeader("pragma", "public")` ?

Comment: same results.  one thing to note, the code above works with IE in debug mode, but when I compile to release mode and try locally, it returns the page name instead of the file name.

Comment: What's the .NET version used in your project?

Comment: we're targeting asp.net 4.0 and we're using sql server 2008.

Comment: ASP.NET Prior to 4.5 is unaware of IE10, which may cause issues. I am unaware of file-download issues, but this also could be affected. If you cannot switch to 4.5 - try updating browser definition file in your project: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: First of all, just quoting this way is naive; the filename may contain characters for which this kind of quoting isn't sufficient. Check RFC 6266.

That being said: I recommend obtaining the header field values that actually get onto the wire.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, it work in IE8, sorry I don't have IE10 installed to test:

```
// myFile = an object containing information about the file being served
Response.Clear()
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1))
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)
Response.ContentType = myFile.contentType
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=" & myFile.targetFilename)
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes) // your code
//Response.WriteFile(myFile.sourceFilename, True) // my code
Response.End()
```

The caching stuff probably isn't necessary for you.

I use `Response.WriteFile` because I stored my files on the filesystem instead of in a database/byte array. You may be able to just drop in your call to `BinaryWrite`.

The only other difference is your double quotes around the filename in your Content-Disposition header. I know that [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) show them, but my code works without them.

Comment: Thanks Walter, I just tried that and it gave an error.  WriteFile is expecting a physical file, which in my case doesn't exist.  I tried with and without quotes in the filename with no luck also.  I'd rather not rewrite this module to store files in the filesystem, but i may have to :(

Comment: That's correct, `WriteFile` expects a string containing the path to a physical file. What happens if you use my code, except replace my `WriteFile` with your `BinaryWrite`. I don't see why you'd need to switch to file system, I think it's just an issue of writing your HTTP response correctly.

Comment: that yields the same result.  I'm not sure if you see my comment above but one thing to note, my initial code works with IE in debug mode, but when I compile to release mode and try locally (or on the server), it returns the page name instead of the file name.

Comment: That behavior sounds familiar, I think I've seen it where it uses the aspx filename when running in the VS debugger, but works file when running from IIS. It could be some difference between IIS and [Visual Studio Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx).